# Implementing a range slider unto a 3d isosurface in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, range, slider, isosurface

I am attempting to add a range slider into a 3d isosurface that represents temperature in a room. [Slider](https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/), [isosurface example](https://plotly.com/python/3d-isosurface-plots/)

I have been smashing my head against the wall trying to implement this, several times I have gotten the surface to execute, with no sign of the newly implemented code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.